# Kubernetes ingress path based working well

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Hello I am new to kubernetes and i need some help.

I want use kubernetes ingress path for my 2 different nuxt project.

First / path working well but my

second /v1 path not get resources like .css and .js

My first deployment and service yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-1
  labels:
    app: nginx1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx1
        image: st/itmr:latest  "can't show image"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx1-svc
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    app: nginx1
```

My second deployment and service yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx2
  labels:
    app: nginx2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx2
        image: st/itpd:latest  "can't show image"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx2-svc
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    app: nginx2
```

And there is the my ingress yaml file:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: some.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx1-svc
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /v1
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx2-svc
            port:
              number: 8080
```

I tought using nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1 would be work for me bu its not.

I don't know where is the problem so help me.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? Could you attach your logs?

Comment: Oh tnks you its done by just switched my project path

Answer (score 1):

To clarify I am posting a community wiki answer.

The problem here was resolved by switching the project path.

See more about ingress paths [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#path-types).